# How can I get array form file json and arrage Index value and result return array json [WITH PHP]

Tags: php, json

Here is my array in Json file

```
{
  "0": { "type": 12, "index": 115, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "4": { "type": 12, "index": 119, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },   
  "1": { "type": 12, "index": 116, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "3": { "type": 12, "index": 118, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "2": { "type": 12, "index": 117, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" }
}
```

results to be achieved from php as json

```
{
  "0": { "type": 12, "index": 115, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "1": { "type": 12, "index": 116, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "2": { "type": 12, "index": 117, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "3": { "type": 12, "index": 118, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "4": { "type": 12, "index": 119, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to array, sort by index, then convert to obj.

**PHP version**

```
$json = '{
    "0": { "type": 12, "index": 115, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "4": { "type": 12, "index": 119, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "1": { "type": 12, "index": 116, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "3": { "type": 12, "index": 118, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "2": { "type": 12, "index": 117, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" }
}';

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
usort($obj, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a["index"] > $b["index"]) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($a["index"] < $b["index"]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

return $obj;
// or
return json_encode($obj);
```

**JS version**

```js
var obj = {
  "0": { "type": 12, "index": 115, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "4": { "type": 12, "index": 119, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },   
  "1": { "type": 12, "index": 116, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "3": { "type": 12, "index": 118, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
  "2": { "type": 12, "index": 117, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" }
}

function sort_obj_by_index(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    arr.push(obj[key]);
  }

  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.index > b.index) {
      return 1
    } else if (a.index < b.index) {
      return -1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })

  var result = {}
  arr.forEach((value, key) => result[key] = value)

  return result;
}

var result = sort_obj_by_index(obj)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $json = '{
    "0": { "type": 12, "index": 115, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "4": { "type": 12, "index": 119, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "1": { "type": 12, "index": 116, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "3": { "type": 12, "index": 118, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" },
    "2": { "type": 12, "index": 117, "showType": 1, "achievementType": 0, "desc": "WING" }
}';

$obj = json_decode($json, true); // convert json to array
var_dump($obj); // print array before sorting
ksort($obj); // sorting
var_dump($obj); // print array after sorting
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$filedata = file_get_contents('test.json');
$details = json_decode($filedata, true);
ksort($details);
```

Here 2 option

```
echo json_encode($details, 
JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// https://unminify.com/
```

OR

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode($details, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```